# Can't run script of MongoDB Atlas URL using node to database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I'm currently following along with a MDN tutorial [Express Local Library Part 3](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/mongoose). I've done everything correctly, that I know of, so far. I made a database then a cluster with MongoDB Atlas and am now trying to upload my data from a file `populatedb.js` by command `node populatedb <my MongoDB Atlas URL here>` but it doesn't work at all. I've linked it to the `apps.js` file with the correct URL (or so I think).

I'm getting this returned in the console:

```
___________-MacBook-Air express-locallibrary-tutorial % node populatedb 'mongodb+srv://_________:_______________@cluster0.mhzo6.mongodb.net/local_library?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/________/Desktop/express-locallibrary-tutorial/populatedb'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

[image]
[image]

I've even deleted my database, cluster, organization and everything and remade them exactly the same but still to no avail.

Comment: Well, Node.js is arguing it can't find the file `populatedb` in the directory `express-locallibrary-tutorial/`. Are you sure that is the correct file to run? The extension matters.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, I'm just typing in everything exactly as the tutorial says that's why I'm so confused why it can't find the path.

Comment: `node script.js arg1 argN` — will make the Node.js interpreter to run `script.js` file and pass `arg1` & `argN` as command-line arguments to the script. I see you have `.js` suffix missing.

Comment: hmm I just ran populatedb.js with url followed in single quotes and same error thrown. the tutorial left it out so i did too. could it be something to do with my cluster? this is the first time I'm linking to a database since I've started learning coding

Comment: it's just not letting me connect, i've tried renaming and deleting the file.

Comment: You've written `node populatedb URL`, should be `node populatedb.js URL`. That's why the interpreter says it can't find `populatedb`, as there is just `populatedb.js`. Filenames are different. If `populatedb.js` returns an error, then could you extend the post, please?

Comment: alright just uploaded the new error :)

Comment: Could you try `node ./populatedb.js URL`, please? As I may understand it looks for the package with the same name inside `./node_modules/` folder and that is not what we want. We want it to run the script from the current `./` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

*[for those of you stumped on this tutorial this will most likely be the cause!]*

The tutorial made it very easy to misunderstand and create a secondary folder of the same name as the root in the root...[or perhaps and more likely its that we are still beginners and its very easy to misunderstand and make this simple mistake.] In creating the initial express project https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/skeleton_website at tutorial 2 "creating the project" I had accidentally made the simple mistake of creating my own express-locallibrary-tutorial folder/project in VS code then ran all of the cmds from the integrated terminal instead of the external terminal. This is what caused the double folder.

I was easily able to work around this just by making sure I was in the correct folder when running node/nodemon and made sure to path correctly for all routes just to "cover up" the mistake which I believed was no big deal... This caused me to have to trash my entire project. I had actually finished this tutorial but once it came to launching it to Heroku I quickly realized that it wasn't worth it to attempt to fix everything and best to restart it from the beginning because Heroku can only run scripts from the /root/ as it should [at least so far since this beginner/noob has been troubleshooting that is!]

So watch out for that simple mistake all! If you did it too and caught it early it is definitely worth the headache of restarting because it will help you in the long run and is a good lesson of a simple mistake, or it is for me!!